# How to access database from configure method of a symfony task

Tags: symfony1, task

You can create a symfony "task" by extending `sfBaseTask`; see http://www.symfony-project.org/cookbook/1_1/en/tasks for more details.

However, I cannot see how to set up a database connection in the `configure` section. I want to do this so that I can have the `detailedDescription` property show some options that are only defined in the database.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Are there any options? Just do it the regular way.. with Doctrine::getTable

Comment: I have re-written the question to clarify the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check out the way symfony [creates a custom Task Skeleton](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/13-Leveraging-the-Power-of-the-Command-Line) (`./symfony generate:task yourTaskName`), you would see code that looks like this inside the execute function:

```
protected function execute([..])
{
     $databaseManager = new sfDatabaseManager($this->configuration);
     $connection = $databaseManager->getDatabase($options['connection'])->getConnection();
[..]
```

The problem with this code is that it uses the default configuration, but if you know what connection you want to open (check your `database.yml` or `schema.yml` to figure out the name) it should be really easy, with code that looks like this:

```
protected function configure()
{
         $databaseManager = new sfDatabaseManager(sfProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend'‌​, 'prod', true));
         $connection = $databaseManager->getDatabase("the_name_of_your_connection")->getConnection();  
[..]
```

Then you can access your models the usual way, e.g.:

```
    $myItem = Doctrine_Core::getTable('item')->find(14);
    echo $myItem->getId();
```

Comment: The code `sfDatabaseManager($this->configuration)` does not work; what does work is `$databaseManager = new sfDatabaseManager(sfProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'prod', true))`

Comment: So true, i modified it to add it! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Doctrine, the best way to do that is defining a method into the php model file. The model's files are located into /PROJECT/lib/model/doctrine/MODEL_NAMETable.class.php

Be carefull with the MVC model!

Once you have your own method, the way to call it is: `Doctrine_Core::getTable('TABLE_NAME')->miNewMethod($params-if-any);`

I hope I'll help you!